# Sql Query to get latest query

Tags: mysql

```
id  emp_id  prev_emp_status updated_emp_status  updated_at
1   1         1               7                  2018-05-29 0:00:05
2   2         1               2                  2018-05-29 0:09:26
3   1         1               2                  2018-05-29 0:10:29
4   3         1               2                  2018-05-29 0:11:38
5   2         1               7                  2018-05-28 0:00:00
```

This table captures updates of employment status with time. I want to write a sql query to get all the employee ids whose status was changed latest from 1 to something else on the previous date.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if it works for you. Am typing the query on my phone and havent tested. Please excuse.

select emp_id, max(id) as latest_upd_rec from table where prev_emp_status=1 and updated_emp_status!=1 and updated_at=SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)
group by emp_id;